# Requests.get using VPN in chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome

I basically want the code below to open the `url` using chrome in the requests.get and then find the content of the title tag using BeautifulSoip. How can I open the url using chrome and proceed the way I have in the code from line 4.

```
url=''
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/51.0.2704.106 m'}
r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers=headers)
    for line in r.iter_lines():
        soup = BeautifulSoup(line)
        for row in soup.findAll('title'):
            title=row.string
            print title
            break
```

I have Hola VPN installed on my chrome browser. When I run this code, I do get the result but not according to the country that I want (UK). I get the URL according to my own country. As the URL isn't available in my country that means I get no output. What piece of code should I add to the code above to use the UK VPN address? I'm using Windows 10 if it matters.

Help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: What is not working?  I just used your first 3 lines of code to open a website.  It worked fine for me

Comment: I am actually using Hola on chrome to browse using a VPN server. I basically want to use that server instead of my own in the code to fetch the Url.

Comment: Since my country doesn't support that URL, I want to fetch details about it using requests here.

Comment: @joelgoldstick How can I use a VPN server for this code?

Comment: Using a VPN seems to me to be a completely different question.  Perhaps you can describe a little more in your question.

Comment: @joelgoldstick Please check edits. Thanks :)

Comment: @joelgoldstick Either the VPN or is there a way to use a chrome extension in python. I gues that'd work too!

Comment: @joelgoldstick Can you please suggest someting?